# How to Manually throw error Pages in Play Framework?

Tags: java, http, playframework, http-status-code-404

How do I manually throw a `404` or `500` error in Play framework 1.2.x?

I am currently rendering the `404.html` and `500.html` templates using `renderTemplate()` method. But how do I do it the proper way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play [`Controller`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/mvc/Controller.html) has `error()` and `notFound()` methods for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you can just invoke static `error()` method from Controller which will give 500 status.

Answer (score 0):

return internalServerError(filledForm.errorsAsJson());