# Respond to invalid JSON requests with application/json type response

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using Play framework 2.2.3. I want to respond to invalid JSON requests with a JSON response saying response type is invalid JSON like

```
{"message": "invalid json"}
```

but Play by default sends html data. I am using

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
```

annotation for my action method in the controller class. How do I send a JSON response instead of the default html response?

Comment: might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699595/how-to-manually-throw-error-pages-in-play-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play automaticaly sets content type depending on type of returned data, so use valid JSON object, you don't need to use `@BodyParser` for that, `badRequest` additionally sets response status to `400`

```
public static Result someAction() {
    ObjectNode answerObj = Json.newObject();
    answerObj.put("message", "invalid json");
    return badRequest(answerObj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to get the JSON payload in the request as `JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();` assuming that content-type is `application/json`. How do I handle for cases when the `content-type` is not `application/json`?

Comment: If you are sure that body is a JSON-like String you can just parse it: `JsonNode node = Json.parse(request().body())`;

Comment: But I also have to handle cases when the body is not JSON. It can be html, xml etc. In those cases, I want to send a message saying only JSON content type is allowed. Please help.

Comment: Use try/catch block then, Json.parse() throws an exception if it can't  parse valid JSON string

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Just a question - how do I accept only one HTTP method like POST and send JSON response for other methods instead of letting Play send html data for 404 error?

Comment: Create additional action for GET method and return JSON with `badRequest()` simple solutions are nice, cause they are nice and simple :) Optionally you can override some method of Global object ie. `onHandlerNotFound`